# Spray Routing Doesn't match anything

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-test, spray-routing

I have tried many things, but no matter what I do in my tests (which simply sends a PUT request to "create a user") the logs do not enter any of the pathPrefix and just go to the end and fail to match anything.

Can anyone offer insight?  Below is the class I have written as well as the simple test (which doesn't even check anything yet)

I know overall it is rather rudimentary and I am not doing things great, but it's just something I threw together to the point where I felt i could do a few quick tests on the routing

```
package system

import akka.actor.{Props, ActorRef, ActorLogging}
import akka.util.Timeout
import spray.http.HttpHeader
import spray.routing.directives.OnCompleteFutureMagnet
import spray.routing.{RequestContext, HttpServiceActor, Route}
import spray.http.StatusCodes._

import scala.concurrent.duration._

import akka.pattern.ask

import system.F_BackBone._

import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

import language.postfixOps

class F_Listener(backbone: ActorRef) extends HttpServiceActor with ActorLogging {
  import context.dispatcher

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

  log.debug("beginning user log\n")

  //TODO write the main listener spawner that acts as the main spray server and binds these listeners to connections
  //TODO must watch the spray side http server actor and die with it

  val route: Route = { uri =>
    log.debug("request received " + uri.unmatchedPath)

    pathPrefix("data") { req =>
      log.debug("data path detected " + req.unmatchedPath + "\n")
      get {
        genericGet(req, GetImage) //URIs for actual data like pictures
      } ~
        path("uploadimage") {
          put { req =>
            genericPut(PutImage(req.request.entity))
          }
        }
    } ~
    pathPrefix("user") { req =>
      log.debug("user path detected" + req.unmatchedPath + "\n")
      get {
        genericGet(req, GetUserInfo)
      } ~
        post {
          genericPost(req, req.request.headers, UpdateUserData)
        } ~
        delete {
          genericDelete(req, DeleteUser)
        }
      pathPrefix("newuser") {
        put { req =>
          genericPut(CreateUser(req.request))
        }
      }
    } ~
    pathPrefix("page") { req =>
      log.debug("page path detected" + "\n")
      get {
        genericGet(req, GetPageInfo)
      } ~
        post {
          genericPost(req, req.request.headers, UpdatePageData)
        } ~
        delete {
          genericDelete(req, DeletePage)
        }
      path("newpage") {
        put { req =>
          genericPut(CreatePage(req.request))
        }
      }
    } ~
    pathPrefix("profile") { req =>
      log.debug("profile path detected" + "\n")
      get {
        genericGet(req, GetProfileInfo)
      } ~ //no need for "createprofile" they are created with the user and can be accessed through the JSON returned with that creation
        post {
          genericPost(req, req.request.headers, UpdateProfileData)
        } //no need to delete profile, deleted with user
    } ~
    pathPrefix("picture") { req =>
      log.debug("picture path detected" + "\n")
      get {
        genericGet(req, GetPictureInfo)
      } ~ //same as for profile, when you upload an image the picture JSON is created
        post {
          genericPost(req, req.request.headers, UpdateImageData)
        } ~
        delete {
          genericDelete(req, DeletePicture)
        }
    } ~
    pathPrefix("album") { req =>
      log.debug("album path detected" + "\n")
      get {
        genericGet(req, GetAlbumInfo)
      } ~
        post {
          genericPost(req, req.request.headers, UpdateAlbumData)
        } ~
        delete {
          genericDelete(req, DeleteAlbum)
        }
      path("createalbum") {
        put { req =>
          genericPut(CreateAlbum(req.request))
        }
      }
    }
    log.error("no path matched" + "\n")
    complete(NotFound, "That resource does not exist")
  }

  /**
   * goes inside of a spray routing "get" and completes the passed message to the backbone given the id
   * it internally converts the remaining request path to a bigint, if this fails it completes with a failure
   * @param req the reques who contains the string to be converted to bigint as an ID
   * @param messageConstructor the case class message (constructor but can be passed with sugar) to compose the bigint into
   * @return returns a route for thed spray routing to go through and side effects the complete needed
   */
  def genericGet(req: RequestContext, messageConstructor: (BigInt) => GetInfo): Route = {
    val id = req.unmatchedPath.toString

    if (!id.contains("/")) { //if this is the last element only
      try {
        val idBig = BigInt(id)
        onComplete(OnCompleteFutureMagnet((backbone ? messageConstructor.apply(idBig)).mapTo[String])) {
          case Success(entityJson) =>
            log.info("get completed successfully: " + messageConstructor + " " + "for " + idBig)
            complete(entityJson)
          case Failure(ex) =>
            log.error(ex, "get failed: " + messageConstructor + " for " + idBig)
            complete(InternalServerError, "Request could not be completed: \n" + ex.getMessage)
        }
      } catch {
        case e: NumberFormatException =>
          log.info("illegally formatted id requested: " + id)
          complete(BadRequest, "Numbers are formatted incorrectly")
      }
    }
    else reject
  }

  /**
   * same as above but for posts, I treid to write a more generic function to repeat rewriting code but it ended up just not being worth the thought
   * @param req request who contains id to parse to bigint
   * @param args arguments to change
   * @param messageConstructor the message to send
   * @return
   */
  def genericPost(req: RequestContext, args: List[HttpHeader], messageConstructor: (BigInt, List[HttpHeader]) => PostInfo) = {
    val id = req.unmatchedPath.toString

    if (!id.contains("/")) {
      try {
        val idBig = BigInt(id)
        onComplete(OnCompleteFutureMagnet((backbone ? messageConstructor.apply(idBig, args)).mapTo[String])) {
          case Success(newEntityJson) =>
            log.info("post completed successfully: " + messageConstructor + " for " + idBig)
            complete(newEntityJson)
          case Failure(ex) =>
            log.error(ex, "get failed: " + messageConstructor + " for " + idBig)
            complete(InternalServerError, "Request could not be completed: \n" + ex.getMessage)
        }
      } catch {
        case e: NumberFormatException =>
          log.info("illegally formatted id requested: " + id)
          complete(BadRequest, "Numbers are formatted incorrectly")
      }
    }
    else reject
  }

  /**
   * same as above except no need to parse a special message since the path tells all and this is for putting, so the fully constructed message gets passed here
   * @param message constructed message to send to the backbone for handling
   * @return
   */
  def genericPut(message: PutInfo) = {
    pathEnd {
      onComplete(OnCompleteFutureMagnet((backbone ? message).mapTo[String])) {
        case Success(newEntityJson) =>
          log.info("put completed successfully: " + message)
          complete(newEntityJson)
        case Failure(ex) =>
          log.error(ex, "put failed: " + message)
          complete(InternalServerError, "Error putting entity: " + ex.getMessage)
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * almost identical to get, should probobly only be one function
   * @param req identical
   * @param messageConstructor identical
   * @return route
   */
  def genericDelete(req: RequestContext, messageConstructor: (BigInt) => DeleteInfo) = {
    val id = req.unmatchedPath.toString

    if (!id.contains("/")) {
      try {
        val idBig = BigInt(id)
        onComplete(OnCompleteFutureMagnet((backbone ? messageConstructor.apply(idBig)).mapTo[String])) {
          case Success(newEntityJson) =>
            log.info("delete completed successfully: " + messageConstructor + " for " + idBig)
            complete(newEntityJson)
          case Failure(ex) =>
            log.error(ex, "get failed: " + messageConstructor + " for " + idBig)
            complete(InternalServerError, "Request could not be completed: \n" + ex.getMessage)
        }
      } catch {
        case e: NumberFormatException =>
          log.info("illegally formatted id requested: " + id)
          complete(BadRequest, "Numbers are formatted incorrectly")
      }
    }
    else reject
  }

  override def receive = runRoute(route)
}

object F_Listener {
  def props(backbone: ActorRef) = Props(new F_Listener(backbone))
}


/*ideas for speed improvements:
parse out arguments before passing to backbone (might help with scaling to distributed system)
genericDelete, Post, Put, and Get are all pretty similar, some functional composition is probobly possible, esp for delete and get
 */

import akka.testkit.TestActorRef
import org.scalatest.{WordSpec}
import spray.http.HttpHeaders
import spray.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest
import system.F_Listener

class FakebookRoutingTests extends WordSpec with ScalatestRouteTest {
  val route = TestActorRef(new F_Listener(null)).underlyingActor.route
  //implicit val host = DefaultHostInfo(HttpHeaders.Host("fake.fakebook.com"), false)

  "the route" should {

    "succeed on path to create a user" in {
      Put("/user/newuser") ~> route ~> check {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using path("newuser") instead of pathPrefix("newuser")

Comment: Well it didn't even enter the pathPrefix("user") but I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `req =>` helps. If I remember correctly, `put`, `get`, `post` etc. don't provide any arguments for directives. Same goes for `path`. Removing `uri =>` may also be needed.

Update:

If `req =>` is to stay, then all calls finalizing the request should be called on that object. So, for example, instead of `complete(entityJson)` there should be `req.complete(entityJson)` on the top-most context object.

For given code top-most block with context is the first one containing `uri` so somewhere in the code there should be a call to `uri.complete`.

Comment: Those definately provide an execution context, I'm using it to pass to my function, and I'm not even entering the path prefix (unless traversal doesn't work that way and must match a full path) but perhaps the function filters don't need it

Comment: If you want to keep using `req =>` and context, then all `complete` calls should be called on that context. For example, `req.complete(newEntityJson)`.

Comment: ok ive tried the other things, nothing worked not even adding a direct path like path("user" / "newuser") { complete("test") } so im going to try that next

Comment: I've checked something and updated my answer. Spray may sometimes be quite unintuitive.

Comment: so that worked!!! I removed the lower level req => s and changed uri => to req and it worked!  Now I just need to run a test for each path and be certain they all follow this rule.  Can you explain why completing wasn't working before???  I mean the request is the same, the only thing that changed was unmatchedPath, right?

Comment: Glad it worked. I'll try to tell what I know about routes. Directive `complete` on its own is actually a functional that returns a functional object (?) - it behaves like it can take more groups of parameters. When you defined context on your own then spray cannot do its tricks. You can try and instead of `ctx.complete(json)` actually call `complete(json)(ctx)`. This returns an actual route.